# Progress Developer Studio 11.6 doesn't auto compile cls file

Tags: eclipse, openedge, progress-4gl

It usually compiled automatically when saving file but now it doesn't work that way.

Error is shown when the class file is compiled manually. (Please find the attached screenshot).

[image: When saving file / Before Compile]

[image: After compile manually]

How to fix it to be able to compile automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found how to auto compile when saving based on https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/pdsoe/editor-build-options.html

1. Go to Window > Preferences > Global > Workspace, un-tick build automatically.

2. Go to Window > Preferences > Progress OpenEdge > Editor > Build, tick Compile on save if required.